# Scraping data from webpage with Javascript Query Information

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am looking to scrape data from pages like the one below:

http://elofootball.com/country.php?countryiso=ENG&season=2007-2008

Specifically, I want the W/D/L statistics from the 3rd table with all the clubs. You do have to press the "statistics" button for this to show. I am looking to scrape the data for about 55 countries across 10 years.

I've developed some code to scrape similar sites using BeautifulSoup. The code works on this site, but the vast majority of cells return blanks. A few random ones do return data.

I am guessing this is due to the fact that the page uses a javascript query? I have heard about using selenium, but need some help on getting that set up and/or wondering if there is a quicker way, since I would think Selenium would take a ton of time to go through approximately 500 web pages.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Then I have a list of dictionaries created. For example,

```
    #create a dictionary for league and iterate over seasons
    dct_AUT = {}
    dct_BEL = {}
    dct_BGR = {}
for m in range(2007,2019):
    dct_AUT['df_AUT_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame() 
    dct_BEL['df_BEL_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_BGR['df_BGR_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
```

Then I loop through the URLs:

```
#list of URL bases for each league
league_urls = (['http://elofootball.com/country.php?countryiso=AUT&season=',
                'http://elofootball.com/country.php?countryiso=BEL&season=',
                'http://elofootball.com/country.php?countryiso=BGR&season='])
```

This is the scraping portion:

```
#Scraping part
#The first loop is for each url in our URL-list
for l in range(0, len(league_urls)):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    #The second loop is for each year we want to scrape
    for n in range(2007,2019):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        df_soccer1 = None
        url = league_urls[l] + str(n) + str('-') + str(n+1)
        headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

        

        #Table 1 with information about the value
        table = soup.find("div", {"id" : "Stats"})

        team = []
        totalp = []
        totalw = []
        totald = []
        totall = []
        totalgf = []
        totalga = []
        tier = []
        leaguep = []
        leaguew = []
        leagued = []
        leaguel = []
        leaguegf = []
        leaguega = []
        leaguepts = []
        cupp = []
        cupw = []
        cupd = []
        cupl = []
        cupgf = []
        cupga = []
        europ = []
        eurow = []
        eurod = []
        eurol = []
        eurogf = []
        euroga = []
        


        for row in table.find_all('tr'):
            try:
                col = row.find_all('td')
                team_ = col[1].text
                totalp = col[3].text
                totalw = col[4].text
                totald = col[5].text
                totall = col[6].text
                totalgf = col[7].text
                totalga = col[8].text
                tier = col[9].text
                leaguep = col[10].text
                leaguew = col[11].text
                leagued = col[12].text
                leaguel = col[13].text
                leaguegf = col[14].text
                leaguega = col[15].text
                leaguepts = col[16].text
                cupp = col[17].text
                cupw = col[18].text
                cupd = col[19].text
                cupl = col[20].text
                cupgf = col[21].text
                cupga = col[22].text
                europ = col[23].text
                eurow = col[24].text
                eurod = col[25].text
                eurol = col[26].text
                eurogf = col[27].text
                euroga = col[28].text
                team.append(team_)
                totalp.append(totalp_)
                totalw.append(totalw_)
                totald.append(totald_)
                totall.append(totall_)
                totalgf.append(totalgf_)
                totalga.append(totalga_)
                tier.append(tier_)
                leaguep.append(leaguep_)
                leaguew.append(leaguew_)
                leagued.append(leagued_)
                leaguel.append(leaguel_)
                leaguegf.append(leaguegf_)
                leaguega.append(leaguega_)
                leaguepts.append(leaguepts_)
                cupp.append(cupp_)
                cupw.append(cupw_)
                cupd.append(cupd_)
                cupl.append(cupl_)
                cupgf.append(cupgf_)
                cupga.append(cupga_)
                europ.append(europ_)
                eurow.append(eurow_)
                eurod.append(eurol_)
                eurol.append(eurod_)
                eurogf.append(eurogf_)
                euroga.append(euroga_)
            except:
                pass

    

        df_soccer1 = pd.DataFrame({'Team': team[1:], 'Season': [n]*(len(team)-1), 'totalp': totalp[1:], 'totalw': totalw[1:],
                                    'totald': totald[1:], 'totall': totall[1:], 'totalgf': totalgf[1:], 'totalga': totalga[1:],
                                    'tier': tier[1:], 'leaguep': leaguep[1:], 'leaguew': leaguew[1:], 'leagued': leagued[1:],
                                    'leaguel': leaguel[1:], 'leaguegf': leaguegf[1:], 'leaguega': leaguega[1:],
                                    'leaguepts': leaguepts[1:], 'cupp': cupp[1:], 'cupw': cupw[1:], 'cupd': cupd[1:],
                                    'cupl': cupl[1:], 'cupgf': cupgf[1:], 'cupga': cupga[1:], 'europ': europ[1:],
                                    'eurow': eurow[1:], 'eurod': eurod[1:], 'eurol': eurol[1:], 'eurogf': eurogf[1:],
                                    'euroga': euroga[1:]})
        
        #Store all dictionaries in a list
        dct_all = [dct_AUT,dct_BEL,dct_BGR]
        
        #Merge df_soccer1 and df_soccer2 for each season
        dct_all[l]['df_bl_%s' % n] = df_soccer1
```

Then I do some combining of the data into a single data set.

Any thoughts on why I am getting most as blanks? There seems to be no pattern as to which ones are blank and which scrape the data.

Comment: You confirmed by printing the  `soup` and the `table` to see what's in there?

Comment: Correct. Now that I am looking at it again, inside the html you can get the items, and it pulls the team name variable. However, the rest are still blank. Does it have something to do with the way the td's are structured. Here's how they are in the html:

<td>25</td>

Comment: can't you simply `pd.read_html` and get the whole table?

Comment: Ahh that would probably be easier. I did figure out the issue. I forgot to put _ after the items when it was searching.

For example, I put: "team_ = col[1].text" but also "totalp = col[3].text". Since everything but team was missing the _, they appeared as blanks

Comment: I just tried and `pandas` gets it. That rids you of, I don't know 40 lines of code..?I'd go with that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that to simplify